# Failed to get data from ajax for x-editable

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, x-editable

I want to make validation to change the email address. I managed to make the email validation not be blank.
But when I validate if the email entered is already exist in the database, I fail to retrieve the data from ajax.

Here is my code:

```
$('#email').editable({
    validate: function(value) {
        if ($.trim(value) == '') {
            return 'This field is required';
        } else if (sum_email(value) > 0) {
            return 'Email already exists';
        }
    }
});

function sum_email(email) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/editable/user/sum_email",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            email: email
        },
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    })
}
```

Code on the controller :

```
public function sum_email()
{
    $email = $this->model->getUserByEmail($this->input->post('email'))->num_rows();

    echo $email;
}
```

I checked the data from the controller has returned a value like this : 
[data from the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4pYo.png)

It works if in the sum_email function I return 1

```
function sum_email(email) {
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: can you show  your model code